# Service to Sync contacts and calendar between OS X and Windows 8

Tags: macos, windows-8, microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar

Is there any Service that I can use to sync my contacts and calendar between multiple Windows 8 and Mac OS X devices? I currently have all my data at iCloud and previously at Google, but Google can't sync to Windows any more. Is there any Service I can use that supports protocols that OS X and Windows 8 (Outlook) can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Google for both contacts and calendar on Windows 8 and OSX Mountain Lion.

Both operating systems have built-in Google sync capabilities.

Comment: Is it possible to sync Google Contacts and Calendar on Windows Phone 8 and iOS?

Comment: I have not used WinPhone 8.  But my iPhone 4S syncs my google contacts and calendar just fine.

Comment: After having another look myself, I guess Google is the best option to sync Windows 8 and OS X.

Comment: It works well for me.  If you have questions about specific aspects of it I encourage you to search SuperUser and post more questions as needed.